# Firebase usage. How to decide to what is better, firestore or firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter

Project is dating app, writing on Flutter. Why is firestore better than firebase database? Or how do decide what better suits for a project? Need someone who has a good knowledge in Firebase and can explain me questions I have... not for free, of course... just do not have time to learn this technology and have to finish project in 2 weeks... please, guys, need your help, please

Answer (score 1):

read the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

it's the first result of a google search.